# Set dynamic background to a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to set background to my bootstrap modal which has the following scenario,
I have a dynamically changing images which will be shown as a background image of the model
These images are retrieved by making a REST call to getFile/getImage (REST call retrieves the images from file system).
When I use something like This(code below) in Html file in any div tag it works fine

```
<img style="width: 100%" src="getFile/getImage/dynamicBikeImage" alt="Dynamic Bike Image">
```

But when I use the same to set the background of my modal using javascript it fails.

here is code I have tried

```
$('#bikeModal').css({'background-size':'100%, 100%','background':'linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url(getFile/getImage/dynamicBikeImage)'});
```

I have also tried making ajax call something like this

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/getFile/getImage/dynamicBikeImage",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(res) {

            $('#bikeModal').css({'background-size':'100%, 100%','background':'linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url(getFile/getImage/dynamicBikeImage)'});
        }
    });
```

The confusing thing is if I use an image present in the static folder then it works as expected e.g.

```
$('#bikeModal').css({'background-size':'100%, 100%','background':'linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url(static/images/bikebg.jpg)'});
```

Here is a snap to better visualize what I am trying to achieve(which was achieved by using the image in static folder of the workspace)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a solution like this? Try putting the image url in double quotes.

```js
function setbackgroundformodalcontent() {
    $('#myModal .modal-content').css({'background-size':'100%, 100%','background':'linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-258/64/_Team_Work-512.png")'});
};

function setbackgroundformodal() {
    $('#myModal').css({'background-size':'100%, 100%','background':'linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-258/64/_Team_Work-512.png")'});
};
```

```html
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Modal Example</h2>
    <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
    <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-primary"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#myModal"
    >
    Open modal
    </button>

    <button onclick="setbackgroundformodalcontent()">Set Background For Modal</button>
    <button onclick="setbackgroundformodal()">Set Background For Modal Behind</button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            &times;
            </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            Modal body..
        </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
            Close
            </button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, the image should get set as background without any button click and the url is my own rest api which retrieves the image from file system

Comment: @Supager Yes I understand. Rather than making use of api call I made use of a button click. have you tried putting the image url in double quotes? That's my point.

Comment: Ok, not I haven't yet, will try after this comment

Comment: Thank You :) Added background in two different ways.

Comment: In your original code it seems you are missing image file type extensions ie .jpg, maybe part of your original problem.